# Issue with <curses.h>;<curse.h>;<conio.h> in G++ Linux terminal

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, g++

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #include <curses.h>  //#include <conio.h>
    int main()
    {
    initscr();
    char dir='a';
    int x=10,y=10;
    cout<<"Please press ENTER for EXIT...\n";
    while (dir != '\r')
    {
     cout<<"\n Your coordinates: " << x << ", " << y;
     cout<<"\n Select your destination: (N,S,E,W): ";
     dir = getch();
     if(dir =='n')
     y--;
      else if(dir=='s'))
     y++;
      else if(dir=='e'))
     x++;
      else if(dir=='w'))
     x--;
     }
    return 0;
    }
```

Giving error

```
msi@MSI-VR610:~/Desktop$ g++ adelseif.cpp -o adelseif
adelseif.cpp:5:42: fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory
#include <curses.h>  //#include <conio.h>
```

So i am trying to use the alternative directory curse.h and ncurse.h and other combination but it doesn t compile anyway

Comment: Have you installed curses lib on your machine?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-error-cursesh-no-such-file-directory/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to install the appropriate package; for Ubuntu, this is [libncurses5-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libncurses5-dev); for Fedora it appears to be [ncurses-devel](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/ncurses-devel).  Use your package manager (apt-get, yum, etc.) to install it.

You need to link in the library too; do this by adding "-lcurses" or "-lncurses" do your compile command (both worked on Ubuntu; I'm not sure about other distributions).

Your code has extra right parentheses in the "else if ..." lines; you'll get more detail when you compile with curses.h available.